# Integration: U-Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Question:(part a)
By using the substitution, $ u=2x+7$
So here is what I did, however, halfway through I had to look at wolframalpha, and don't quite understand what they do to get the answer.

$\int$ $x$$\sqrt{2x+7}$ $dx$

$du$=$2 $ $dx$

$=\frac{1}{4}$$\int$$(u-7)$$\sqrt{u}$ $du$

$=\frac{1}{4}$$\int$$(u^3/_2-7\sqrt{u})$ $du$

$=\frac{1}{4}$$\int$$(u^3/_2 $$du$$ -\frac{7}{4})$ $\int$$\sqrt{u}$ $du$

Here where they separate the integrals, I don't understand why they do it and if it is a calculus principle I do not know, and if that's the case, can someone please explain to me? thanks.  Also this next step as they integrate, they don't integrate the fraction $\frac{7}{4}$,which reminds me, how do they even get the fraction? It must be some piece of calculus about Integration I am missing out on.

$=$$\frac{u^5/_2}{10}$$-$$\frac{7}{4}$ $\int$$\sqrt{u}$ $du$

I do, however, understand after this point, but of-course I am unsure of the method used above.

$=$$\frac{u^5/_2}{10}$$-$$\frac{7u^3/_2}{6}$ $+$ $C$

$=$$\frac{(2x+7)^5/_2}{10}$$-$$\frac{7(2x+7)^3/_2}{6}$$+$ $C$

$\therefore$$\int$ $x$$\sqrt{2x+7}$ $dx$ = $\frac{\sqrt(2x+7)^5}{10}$$-$$\frac{7\sqrt(2x+7)^3}{6}$$+$ $C$
Which indeed is the correct answer.

Can anyone help me with how wolframalpha split the integral at the middle part and also why they didn't integrate $\frac{7}{4}$.Help is greatly appreciated thank you.

(part B) - I don't have a clue on how to do this one.
It's the same integral however they make, $u^2=2x+7$

if anyone can help me with this as well please?

Comment: Is this $u^{\frac{3}{2}}$ or $\frac{u^3}{2}$?

Comment: it's to the power, the LaTeX just does that for some reason.

Comment: You can see the correct TeX command by right clicking on an element that's displayed correctly in a comment, question or answer and then selecting Show Math As > TeX Commands

Comment: That's ok. These pages are also helpful:  $$ \\ $$http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation  $$ \\ $$ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can you explain what does $\frac{1}{4}\int(u^{3/2}du-\frac{7}{4})\int \sqrt{u}du$ mean? I think there's something wrong with the order of parantheses.

Comment: I was asking myself the same question, what does it mean? It was WolframAlpha.

Comment: Advice: Don't use Wolfram for simple integrations like this.

Comment: Dearly noted. @Spock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u^2 = 2x + 7$ then $ x = \frac{u^2 - 7}{2}$ and $dx = udu$

$ \int x \sqrt{2x + 7} dx \ = \ \int \frac{u^2 - 7}{2} \sqrt{u^2} u du \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \int (u^4 - 7u^2) du$

$ \frac{1}{2} [\frac{u^5}{5} - \frac{7u^3}{3} ] \ + \ C \ = \ \frac{ (2x + 7)^2 \sqrt{2x + 7} }{10} \ - \ \frac{ 7(2x + 7) \sqrt{2x + 7} }{6} \ + \ C$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $7u$ instead of $7u^2$? because of the $\frac{1}{2}$ cancels out with $u^2$?

Shouldn't the whole thing be ($u^3-7$)

Comment: But there's another u afterwards: $$\ \int \frac{u^2 - 7}{2} \sqrt{u^2} u du \ $$

Comment: Oh okay nevermind, I forgot about the $udu$, thank you, and also I don't know which one to tick as the answer, they both answer the question.

Comment: lol. flip a coin!

Comment: The $ \frac{1}{2} $ is a coefficient , the u^2 is a base with exponent 2 , they do not cancel. Ohhh ... wait ... you're talking about the exponent \frac{1}{2} , yes THAT cancels of course. :)

Comment: I am going to give it to @neofoxmulder, because George you have a lot of Reputation compared to him. But thanks nevertheless.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day. @neofoxmulder I was assuming MATHSUSER meant $\frac{1}{2}$ as in $u^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: MATHUSER , thank you! I have upvoted your interesting question. @George Tomlinson , i'm upvoting your helpful answer so you can be rewarded also. Everybody wins! :)

Comment: @George Tomlinson , yes , that is the better assumption to make. LOL

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already upvoted your answer and the question.

Answer (score 2):

First part.

I think you're making this more complicated than it is.  Your first few steps are good.

$\int$ $x$$\sqrt{2x+7}$ $dx$

$du$=$2 $ $dx$

$=\frac{1}{4}$$\int$$(u-7)$$\sqrt{u}$ $du$

$=\frac{1}{4}$$\int$$(u^{\frac{3}{2}}-7\sqrt{u})$ $du$

Now let's integrate.

$=\frac{1}{4}$$(\frac{2}{5}u^{\frac{5}{2}}-\frac{14}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}})+C$

$=\frac{2u^{\frac{5}{2}}}{20}-\frac{14}{12}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$

$=\frac{u^{\frac{5}{2}}}{10}-\frac{7}{6}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$

Comment: wait, so I can just integrate that normally. Why does wolframalpha show this method? and what is it?

Comment: Don't worry too much about what WA shows. Tou know that the integral of a sum is the sum of the integrals. So, go on !

Comment: Wow I am just stupid for looking at WA, when I could've just integrated normally, thank you. And also for part B, can I just have a hint on where to start, do i make the RHS square root?